# UNIX date converted incorrectly in HIVE

Tags: hive

When I execute this statement in HIVE

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(to_date('2016-03-28 00:00:00'),'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I get

```
OK
2015-12-27 00:00:00
```

Shouldn't it return `2016-03-28 00:00:00` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The UPPER CASE string for the date pattern string that you have mentioned is wrong. It should be "yyyy-MM-dd"

Please use the following which should fix your error

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(to_date('2016-03-28 00:00:00'),'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Comment: This is subtle enough to make me vote the question up.Is there an underlying reason for the mixed case? It appears pretty random to me, and the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) on `FROM_UNIXTIME` does not go into detail.

Comment: @vadimzilberleyb Happy It worked. Please accept the answer.